# R-values appear to provide incomplete support for unnamed temporaries, or am I missing something here?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, move

R-values appear to provide incomplete support for unnamed temporaries, or am I missing something here?

---

C++11 provides excellent support for rvalues to implement move semantics, useful for converting expensive allocate and copy cycles into fast and cheap moves in constant time, similar to moving a reference.  But C++11 came late in the game, and by then I had a fully developed solution to the costly unnamed temporaries problem, using the class-based solution outlined below.

Only when I recently attempted to replace my solution with with "modern" C++11 move constructors, did I discover rvalue management doesn't cover important cases that the class-based solution covers.  A representative example is the expression A + B.  When A is an unnamed temporary (rvalue), an in-place implementation of A += B is appropriate, when A is not an unnamed temporary (lvalue), A + B computes a new result.  But C+11 rvalue support appears to address only a right argument rvalue, but not a left rvalue.

By extension, this limitation affect all other operators and functions on the base type that could benefit from treating *this as an rvalue when appropriate.  Note that A + B can even be computed as B += A, when A is an lvalue and B is an rvalue.  The benefits from a complete solution can often be applied more to *this rvalues than to right argument rvalues.  If C++11 provides only a half solution here, then the class-based solution below remains significantly superior for many things.  Am I missing something here?

---

So let's derive an unnamed temporary T class from the class of S values, add appropriate constructors, assignments, operators and functions to S and T, then substitute T for S as the return type for all functions and operators that return an S result.  With this, we get all the same move semantics as with rvalues, plus support for additional functions and operators that can operate faster on unnamed temporary values in-place.

```
class S {                      // S is a sample base type to extend
protected:
    mutable char* p;           // mutable pointer to storage
    mutable int length;        // mutable current length
    mutable int size;          // mutable current size
public:
    ~S ( );                    // S destructor
    S (char* s);               // construct from data
    S (const S& s);            // from another S
    S (const T& s);            // construct from an unnamed temporary

    T& result ( ) { return (T&)*this; }  // cast *this into a T& (an equivalent to std::move (*this))
    S& take (S& s);                      // free *this, move s to *this, put s in empty/valid state

    S& operator= (const S& s);           // copy s to *this
    S& operator= (const T& s);           // assign from unnamed temporary using take ( )

    S& operator+= (const S& v);          // add v to *this in-place
    S& operator-= (const S& v);          // subtract v from *this in-place
    S& operator<<= (Integer shift);      // shift *this in-place
    S& operator>>= (Integer shift);

    T operator+ (const S& v);       // add v to *this and return a T
    T operator- (const S& v);       // subtract v from *this and return a T
    etc...
};

class T : public S {               // T is an unnamed temporary S
private:
    T& operator= (const T& s);          // no public assignments
    void* operator new (size_t size);   // don't define -- no heap allocation
    void operator delete (void* ptr);
public:
    T (char* s) : S (s) { };            // create a new temporary from data
    T (const S& s) : S (s) { };         // copy a new temporary from a non-temporary
    T (const T& s) : S (s) { };         // move a temporary to new temporary

    T operator<< (int shift) const { return ((S&)*this <<= shift).result ( ); }
    T operator>> (int shift) const { return ((S&)*this >>= shift).result ( ); }

    T operator+ (const S& v) const { return ((S&)*this += v).result ( ); }
    T operator- (const S& v) const { return ((S&)*this -= v).result ( ); }
};
```

Note that this method has demonstrated its correctness and effectiveness across a variety of comprehensive data types (including strings, arrays, large integers, etc) since 2001, so it works without any reference to C++11 features, and relies on no undefined language features.

Comment: You are looking for *ref-qualifier*s.

Comment: This question is very wordy and not particularly clear. Could you rework it to ask a simple question about C++ please. Pretend we've never seen your class before and don't know why it's necessary. (hint: it probably isn't)

Comment: How do you use `T`? Do you have to manually keep track of which variable is a temporary and incur copies to convert non-temporaries to temporaries?

Comment: You haven't shown how you get the efficiency of moves, by stealing data from the `mutable` data members from a `const T&` bound to an `S`? You say no undefined language features, but casting a `S&` to a `T&` and then calling member functions of the `T` type is undefined if it isn't really a `T`.

Comment: Tentatively, T.C. provided the solution--it is ref-qualifiers, but I need to understand that concept more to be sure.  My question was apparently clear enough for T.C. to answer it correctly in less than 30 seconds of my post.  To nwp, there is no manual management, T<--S values are moved, S<--T values are copied as encountered in the expression.  Returning an S through a T moves the S to a T.

Comment: To J. Wakely:  all good comments,  the (S&)T up casts a derived type to its base type, and without any T data or virtual functions, this is guaranteed correct.  T should not be further derived, but doesn't need to be.  The move efficiency is in all the right places, and yes, it steals mutable data.  But remember, this solution works in C++1997, do you have a better 1997 solution?  I have over 16 years of error-free service from this method, while the rest of the world was stuck with copy semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be wrong in your assumptions.  C++ supports rvalues on either the left or the right.

There are two ways to do this.

```
struct noisy {
  noisy() { std::cout << "ctor()\n"; };
  noisy(noisy const&) { std::cout << "ctor(const&)\n"; };
  noisy(noisy &&) { std::cout << "ctor(&&)\n"; };
  noisy& operator=(noisy const&) { std::cout << "asgn(const&)\n"; return *this; };
  noisy& operator=(noisy &&) { std::cout << "asgn(&&)\n"; return *this; };
  ~noisy() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; };
};
struct Bob:noisy {
  int val = 0;
  Bob(int x=0):val(x) {}
  Bob(Bob&&)=default;
  Bob(Bob const&)=default;
  Bob& operator=(Bob&&)=default;
  Bob& operator=(Bob const&)=default;
  friend Bob operator+( Bob lhs, Bob const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend Bob& operator+=( Bob& lhs, Bob const& rhs ) {
    lhs.val += rhs.val;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend Bob operator+=( Bob&& lhs, Bob const& rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs; // uses & overload above
    return std::move(lhs);
  }
};
```

`Bob` uses friend operators to do basically what you want.

This is my preferred solution, friend operators are far more symmetric than member operators are.

```
struct Alice:noisy {
  int val = 0;
  Alice(int x=0):val(x) {}
  Alice(Alice&&)=default;
  Alice(Alice const&)=default;
  Alice& operator=(Alice&&)=default;
  Alice& operator=(Alice const&)=default;
  Alice operator+( Alice const& rhs ) const& {
    return Alice(*this) + rhs;
  }
  Alice operator+( Alice const& rhs ) && {
    *this += rhs;
    return std::move(*this);
  }
  Alice& operator+=( Alice const& rhs )& {
    val += rhs.val;
    return *this;
  }
  Alice operator+=( Alice const& rhs )&& {
    *this += rhs;  // uses & overload above
    return std::move(*this);
  }
};
```

`Alice` uses member functions to do the same.  It has the usual problems with member functions over friend operators.

Notice the use of `&` and `&&` and `const&` *after* the member function arguments.  This is known as the "rvalue reference to `*this`" feature in casual discussion.  It lets you pick which overload based on the r/l value-ness of the object being worked with.

Test code:

```
Bob bob;
Bob b2 = Bob{3}+bob;

Alice alice;
Alice a2 = Alice{3}+alice;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b266453aa83de4).

In neither case, no objects are copied.

Note that I assumed addition was assymetric (despite using an `int` for state). If it was, you can do another efficiency where the lhs is a non-rvalue while the rhs is.

Comment: Your solution is also based on ref-qualifiers, a concept that I had not seen before, and one that didn't appear until very recent compilers (VC++ 2015).  Even now, using the new rvalue references to *this prevents compiling with all but the newest compilers.

Comment: @ChrisCochran It is a C++11 feature.  This both directly addresses your question ("am I mistaken?"), and solves your problem, while matching your question's tags, etc.  If you want to gripe about slow implementation of new C++ language features in MSVC, that is another topic.